# Animar um LinearLayout com o LayoutAnimationController

Tags: android, android-layout

Boa Tarde! 
Tenho um *LinearLayout* que será exibido quando o usuário seleciona um Switch
Para isto criei dois métodos, para fadeIn e fadeOut. Segue:

```
private LayoutAnimationController fadeIn(){
    Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
    AnimationSet set=new AnimationSet(true);
    fadeIn.setDuration(155);
    set.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    set.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
    return  new LayoutAnimationController(set);
}

private LayoutAnimationController fadeOut(){
    AnimationSet set=new AnimationSet(true);
    Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fadeOut.setDuration(255);
    set.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    set.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
    return  new LayoutAnimationController(set);
}
```

O problema ocorre no *fadeIn* , quando  tenta executar o  `onAnimationStart(Animation animation)  mLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }`
O Layout não é exibido!

Alguém saberia qual a forma correta para isto? 
Desde já agardeço, Saudações!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar  **android:animateLayoutChanges="true"** no seu layout pai. isso fara as animações **fadeIn** e **fadeOut** de todos as views filhas, quando você colocá-las como **VISIBLE**, **GONE**, **INVISIBLE** e views adicionadas ou removidas.

***Obs.: funciona a partir do Android 3.0***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Switch
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutFilho"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEXTO" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```